# How to update the no. of child in jpa

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jsf-2, eclipselink

I have the four classes namely

```
@Entity
BookEntry(){
@ManyToOne(cascade = { CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH }, targetEntity =BookEditionModel.class)
    @JoinColumn(referencedColumnName = "book_edt_id", name = "book_edt_id", updatable = true)
    private BookEditionModel bookEdtMcg;
}


@Entity
BookEdition(){
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "bookEdition", cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    private List<BookAuthorModel> bookAuth;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "bookEdition", cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    private List<BookPublisherModel> bookPub;
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "bookEdtMcg", cascade = {CascadeType.REFRESH,CascadeType.ALL},orphanRemoval=true)
    private List<BookEntryModel> bookEntryMcg;
}
@Entity
BookPub{}

@Entity
BookAuth{}
```

i have inserted the book having 4 author in `BookAuth`, 20 numbers of book  in `BookEntry` and 1 publisher in `BookPub` and now  i want to update the above book with 3 author , 15 or 25 numbers of book. How could i update the BookInformation?

Comment: could you please rephrase the last part of the question? I cannot understand the requirement.

Comment: i want to update the no. of child in the bookentry table

Comment: Its a java object.  Read it in, make the changes, merge if required, then commit.  There are quite a few good tutorials if this is what you are stuck with such as http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Employee though it is for a different provider.  If asking for something else, please be more specific on what you are doing and what you have tried.